# Didn't get my rep back after a suspension in Channels

Tags: bug, reputation, account-suspension, stack-overflow-for-teams

Yesterday, I was suspended in our Channel, just because..

After they managed to unsuspend me I was stuck at 1 rep. So basically I "lost" all rep (~115) that I gained before the suspension and had to start over.

The reputation history shows the correct details, but the total rep is off:

[image]

I thought the rep may get recalc'd, but that didn't happen.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_forfeiture_in_the_United_States

Comment: If you're not going to behave yourself - what do you expect :p (posted jovially on behalf of science...)

Comment: **They took your reps!!!**

Comment: That’s what happens when you play with the tools and also why we can’t have nice things.

Comment: @Taryn isn't playing with the tools the entire point of channels alpha? :p

Comment: @Bhargav I think "tools" was meant to cover hammers and screw drivers and such... not the RPGs... :p

Comment: Does `https://stackoverflow.com/c/<team name>/reputation` show you correct rep?

Comment: @Ferrybig yep, that shows the correct rep total

Comment: Don't worry, you still have nine toes left.